# Working with a promise in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I have a function that calls an http.get to an API and it has a return type of promise. I'd like to handle/sort the returned data. Do I need to convert it from a Promise into an array of objects to iterate over it?
Here is the function:

```
  getCandidates(): Promise<Candidate[]> {   
    return this.http.get(url)
      .retry(2)
      .map(x => {
        var result: Candidate[] = x.json();
        return result;
      })
      .toPromise();
  }
```

and I call the function by stating:

```
this.candidates = this.getCandidates();
```

So I now have this candidates object of type `Promise<Candidate[]>` but I'd like to have it be of type `Candidate[]` so I can work with it, e.g. `candidates.length` etc. How should I go about this? Maybe I'm thinking of this the wrong way.

Edit: trying to use the code.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    //Retrieves candidates and stores into an array
    this.getCandidates().then(candidates => this.candidates = candidates);
    console.log(this.candidates);
  }
```

The console logs an empty array. I also tried passing it to a sort function but none of the data was present. Which is strange because in the html if I *ngFor over candidates I get the data (which is why I thought it was working properly before).

Comment: You can do it inside `map`

Comment: `this.getCandidates().then(function(candidates) { ... });`

Comment: @AlekseyL in map would I just push result onto an array?

Comment: @ZacharySchwatz, you can sort (or do whatever you need) and return the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve your candidates in *ngOnInit*, save it into *this.candidates* and do what you want to do with it (sorting,..)

```js
  candidates: Candidate[] = [];
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCandidates().then(candidates => this.candidates = candidates);
  }
  
  getCandidates(): Promise<Candidate[]> {   
    return this.http.get(url)
      .retry(2)
      .map(x => x.json as Candidate[])
      .toPromise();
  }
```

Comment: giving it a shot now, I'm in Ionic so not using ngOnInit but there is ionViewDidLoad which is sufficient in this scenario correct?

Comment: I actually have an issue now, when I try to use this.candidates elsewhere in the code or even try to console.log(this.candidates), it is undefined.

Comment: You have to show the code where you use this.candidates

Comment: It's because of the asynchronous aspect of promise: 

this.getCandidates().then(candidates => this.candidates = candidates); console.log(this.candidates);

In this code, you do console.log(this.candidates) just after calling this.getCandidates(). The console.log is executed before the execution of this.candidates = candidates; this.candidates remains undefined until the promise resolve. If you change your code like below, you'll see this.candidates in console:

 this.getCandidates().then(candidates => {
    this.candidates = candidates;
     console.log(this.candidates);
  });

Comment: thanks, I got it to work that way, instead of calling console log I call my sort function there.